# better write rock paper scissors (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I'm new to **python** and I have made this simple rock paper scissors game but I wonder if there is a better way to program this without a super long if else statement.

```
import random
options = ["scissors", "paper", "rock"]
i = random.randint(0, (len(options) - 1))
playedHand = input("PLay rock, paper or scissors please: ")
computerPlayedHand = options[i]

if playedHand == "rock" and computerPlayedHand == "scissors":
    print("the computer had scissors, you win")
elif playedHand == "rock" and computerPlayedHand == "paper":
    print("the computer had paper, you lose")
elif playedHand == "rock" and computerPlayedHand == "rock":
    print("the computer also had rock, its a tie")
elif playedHand == "paper" and computerPlayedHand == "rock":
    print("the computer had rock, you win")
elif playedHand == "paper" and computerPlayedHand == "scissors":
    print("the computer had scissors, you lose")
elif playedHand == "paper" and computerPlayedHand == "paper":
    print("the computer also had paper, its a tie")
elif playedHand == "scissors" and computerPlayedHand == "paper":
    print("the computer had paper, you win")
elif playedHand == "scissors" and computerPlayedHand == "scissors":
    print("the computer also had scissors, its a tie")
elif playedHand == "scissors" and computerPlayedHand == "rock":
    print("the computer had rock, you lose")
else:
    print("please only state rock, paper or scissors")
```

Comment: I think you'd better put this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Personally, I prefer nested if statements. `if (you have rock)... Indent...  if-else (what computer has)`

Comment: I would use a dictionary mapping `(option1, option2)` [tuple keys] to a result.

Comment: thank you @cricket_007 this made it much cleaner to look at and pitto you're right i placed it on the wrong site so next time i will pay more attention were i place it

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I threw together trying to reuse your code where possible.

The key part is noticing that the `options` list can be treated as a cycle where an option always beats the next option. You can check this by finding the indices and then using modulo to make the indices cyclic.

```
import random

options = ["scissors", "paper", "rock"]  # everything loses to the previous thing
comp_index = random.randint(0, (len(options) - 1))
playedHand = input("Play rock, paper or scissors please: ")
computerPlayedHand = options[comp_index]

try:
    player_index = options.index(playedHand)
except ValueError:
    print("please only state rock, paper or scissors")
else:
    if player_index == comp_index:
        res = "the computer also had {}, its a tie"
    # the key part
    elif (player_index - comp_index) % 3 == 1:
        res = "the computer had {}, you lose"
    else:
        res = "the computer had {}, you win"
    print(res.format(computerPlayedHand))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary to represent which hand beat which can significantly shorten your code. But since we are there, let's make this even neater with an object-oriented solution.

```
import random

class Hand:

    _ordering = {
        'rock': 'scissor',
        'scissor': 'paper',
        'paper': 'rock'
    }

    def __init__(self, kind):
        if kind in self._ordering:
            self.kind = kind
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "It's rock, paper, scissor... Not rock, {}, scissor.".format(kind)
            )

    @classmethod
    def random_hand(cls):
        return cls(random.choice(list(cls._ordering)))

    def beats(self, other):
        return self._ordering[self.kind] == other.kind

playedHand = Hand(input("Play rock, paper or scissors please: "))

computerPlayedHand = Hand.random_hand()

if playedHand.beats(computerPlayedHand):
    print('You won! The computer had {}.'.format(computerPlayedHand.kind))
elif computerPlayedHand.beats(playedHand):
    print('You lost... The computer had {}.'.format(computerPlayedHand.kind))
else:
    print("It's a tie.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any "if" statements other than typical error management. Look at the following example:

```
import random

def play():
    table = [[2, 0, 1],
             [1, 2, 0],
             [0, 1, 2]]

    options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    results = ["Defeat", "Win", "Tie"]
    conv    = {"R": 0 , "P": 1, "S": 2}

    while True:
        i = random.randint(0, (len(options) - 1))
        p = input("Play rock, Paper or Scissors please (R, P, S): ")
        if p not in conv.keys():
            print("Unavailable option. Left the Game.")
            return
        print("Computer played %s. You have a %s"%(options[i], results[table[conv[p]][i]]))

play()
```

If you have a table like this:

```
#          Rock Paper Scissor
# Rock       2    0      1
# Paper      1    2      0
# Scissor    0    1      2
```

...you can make the user play in rows, and the computer in columns. The result is being indexed directly by whatever is the number in the table. Thus playing the game in the example would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible version:

```
import random

try:
    options = [('rock', 'scissors'), ('paper', 'rock'), ('scissors', 'paper')]
    human_choice = int(input("Play rock(0), paper(1) or scissors(2) please: "))
    human_hand = options[human_choice]
    computer_hand = options[random.randint(0, (len(options) - 1))]
    text = "the computer {} {}, {}"

    if human_hand[0] == computer_hand[0]:
        print(text.format("also had", computer_hand[0], "it's a tie"))
    elif human_hand[1] == computer_hand[0]:
        print(text.format("had", computer_hand[0], "you win"))
    else:
        print(text.format("had", computer_hand[0], "you lose"))
except Exception as e:
    print("please only state rock, paper or scissors")
```