# game counter in python

Tags: python, counter

I made the game rock, paper or scissors. I want to implement a game counter, but I can't figure out how to make it work. It is stopped at 1. I want to play more games and the counter to show me the numbers of played games.

```
import random

stop = False
while (not stop):
    games_count = 0

    you = input('Player 1: Please type your choice: rock, paper or scissors: ')

    oponent = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    choice = random.choice(oponent)
    games_count += 1

    print('the oponent choice is: ', choice)

    if choice == you:
        print('DRAW GAME')
    elif choice == 'rock' and you == 'paper':
        print('YOU LOST')
    elif choice == 'rock' and you == 'scissors':
        print('YOU WON')
    elif choice == 'paper' and you == 'rock':
        print('YOU WON')
    elif choice == 'paper' and you == 'scissors':
        print('YOU LOST')
    elif choice == 'scissors' and you == 'rock':
        print('YOU LOST')
    elif choice == 'scissors' and you == 'paper':
        print('YOU WON')
    else:
        print('Wrong answer, please type rock, paper or scissors in your next attempt!')

    answer = input('Do you want to start a new game? (y for yes, any for no): ')

    if answer == 'y':
        print('New game will start')
        print('jocuri terminate: ',games_count)
    elif answer == 'no':
        stop = True
        print('GAME OVER')
    else:
        print('Wrong answer, please type Yes or No in your next attempt!')
        stop = True
```

Comment: Move games_count = 0 somewhere before your while loop.

Comment: You set `games_count` to 0 at the start of the loop, so of course it can never exceed 1.

Comment: Thanks yout are right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counter is reinitialized to `0` at each iteration because it is inside your loop.

```
while not stop:
    games_count = 0
    ...
```

Instead, initialize it outside the loop.

```
games_count = 0
while not stop:
    ...
```

As a sidenote, you might want to look to [other implementations of rock-paper-scissor that do not rely on a big list of if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631069/5079316).